# Multi portal DNN need full URL include default.aspx

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-settings

We have a DNN installation on our windows 2008 server. using ASP.net 4 and full trust.
We define 3 portal on single installation. and used 3 sub domain for them.
the problem is, when we call any subdomain site1.DOMAIN.com it redirect to first portal url, and if we use site1.DOMAIN.com/default.aspx then it show correct portal.
in Portal alias define we use sub domain without / in end of url.
Which setting maybe wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is an odd one, do you perhaps have any other "default" documents in the root of the website, such as default.htm or index.html that is doing a redirect?

edit: If there are no default documents, I would start carefully looking at the Portal Alias settings. Making sure that the aliases are all defined properly ex: subdomain.domain.com